# Doc: Is it correct that the thread running runBlocking blocks?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

The docs on [Your first coroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#your-first-coroutine)﻿ say -

> The name of `runBlocking` means that the thread that runs it (in this case — the main thread) gets *blocked* for the duration of the call, until all the coroutines inside `runBlocking { ... }`  complete their execution

Is it correct that the thread running runBlocking blocks?

If the main thread is blocked, then how the coroutine launched by launch { } in the below code (from the same doc) runs on the main thread??

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { // launch a new coroutine and continue
        delay(1000L) // non-blocking delay for 1 second (default time unit is ms)
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + " World!") // print after delay
    }
    println(Thread.currentThread().name + " Hello") // main coroutine continues while a previous one is delayed
}
```

My understanding is that

- launch{ } created a child coroutine in runBlocking scope
- and runBlocking waits for the completion of this child coroutine, unlike builders like launch{ } or async { } that immediately return after creating the new coroutine
- but runBlocking frees the main thread
- since main thread is free, the new coroutine created by runBlocking also runs on main thread

Here is an output from the above code -

```
main @coroutine#1 Hello
main @coroutine#2 World!
```

Same issue in the documentation of [runBlocking](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html)

> Runs a new coroutine and **blocks** the current thread until its completion. This function should not be used from a coroutine. It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in main functions and in tests.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the documentation you posted for [`runBlocking`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html)

> Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread until its completion.

and [`launch`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html)

> Launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread and returns a reference to the coroutine as a Job.

They both create a new coroutine, it's just that `launch` runs its coroutine asynchronously, and allows the caller to continue running code. `runBlocking` *doesn't* allow the caller to continue *until everything running in that coroutine has finished*. So `runBlocking` doesn't control the behaviour of the stuff *inside* its coroutine, just the execution of the code that's *calling* `runBlocking`.

This tweak to your code might make things clearer:

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        launch {
            delay(1000L)
            println(Thread.currentThread().name + " World!")
        }
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + " Hello")
    }
    // this -follows- the runBlocking statement
    println("Hey I'm runnin' here!")
}
```

```
main @coroutine#1 Hello
main @coroutine#2 World!
Hey I'm runnin' here!
```

So what's happening is:

- `runBlocking` runs, blocking the main thread. The next line won't run until everything in this coroutine has finished!
- `launch` runs, creating a *new* coroutine on the same thread, but without blocking it. The code on the next line will be able to run while this is running, because they're in separate coroutines, but taking turns in little time slices (since they're on the same thread). This coroutine calls `delay` immediately, so even if it runs before the line in the *original* coroutine (the `println` after `launch)` it'll definitely hit its own `println` much later
- the `println` following `launch` runs, since this coroutine is independent of the other one. This coroutine is finished (but the other one is still running)
- the `println` *inside* `launch` runs after its delay. This coroutine has nothing else to do, so it's also finished
- since all the `Job`s in the coroutine launched by `runBlocking` have finished, that blocking coroutine ends, and execution can continue in the scope where it was launched
- that last `println` gets to run, finally!

---

Also just to clear up a possible misunderstanding:

> Is it correct that the thread running runBlocking blocks?
>
> If the main thread is blocked, then how the coroutine launched by launch { } in the >below code (from the same doc) runs on the main thread??

All coroutines run on the same thread as the caller, unless you explicitly tell them not to, or use a *dispatcher* that can move them to a different thread. It's just that the coroutines "take turns" and get a bit of time to execute some code on a thread. So it looks like they're running "at the same time" even when they're not.

So because `launch` doesn't "block", what that means is the coroutine that calls it is *allowed to continue*, getting a bit of time to execute the rest of the code, while the *launched* coroutine also gets some time slots. They can run independently.

But `runBlocking` *does* block, which means it *doesn't get any execution time* until the coroutine it started finishes. It takes a break until the coroutine is done. So it's **not actually blocking the main thread** in the normal sense, otherwise none of the coroutines on that thread could run! It's just blocking execution in its own scope - it's a way to say "nothing else happens here until this job has finished". That's why it's a common `main` function wrapper, to kind of create a world of coroutines that *everything* runs in, and preventing the `main` function from completing and ending the program. But it **does** block anything outside that from running, which is why it's a bad idea in something like Android, where there's other stuff going on with the main thread besides any coroutines you might want to run.

Also, `launch` actually runs on a `CoroutineScope` (i.e. `CoroutineScope.launch`) , which it has access to inside a coroutine - that's why you have to use it inside one! `runBlocking` is a standalone builder function, but the function block you pass in has a type of `CoroutineScope.() -> T` - i.e. it's going to be *passed to* a `CoroutineScope`, like a default one provided by the framework. That `CoroutineScope` is what works out when all its child coroutines have finished, and informs the caller that it's done. `runBlocking` just waits around for that to happen, instead of allowing execution to continue [like the `coroutineScope` builder](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder).

Answer (score 0):

After searching for an answer since I posted this question, and reading through several articles and @cactustictacs answer, I think the words `the current thread gets blocked` puts readers in a mental block forcing them to think that the thread is doing nothing.

While `coroutineScope` just suspends, releasing the underlying thread for other usages, `runBlocking {...}` *doesn't takes itself off the thread* while waiting for its body and all the child coroutines to finish; that's why it is a normal function and not a suspending one. Since all child coroutines inherit the same context (& dispatcher, unless another one is passed) from `runBlocking`, they will *continue* on the same thread. So yes, the *thread is blocked* waiting for runBlocking to finish, but indeed it is busy executing runBlocking body and all its children coroutines.

Also, from documentation of `runBlocking`

> The default [CoroutineDispatcher] for this builder is an internal implementation of event loop that processes continuations in this blocked thread until the completion of this coroutine.

The thread underlying `runBlocking` is busy executing an event loop that processes runBlocking body and all its child coroutines (those that inherit the context from runBlocking). Here is a beautiful Medium post explaining this phantom eventloop [Learning Kotlin Coroutines as a Java Dev (Part II)](https://medium.com/@patson.luk/learning-kotlin-coroutines-as-a-java-dev-part-ii-dfe0d468b65e)

So, the `blocked thread` just means that the thread is busy executing `runBlocking` body, and won't come out unless everything runBlocking does and starts finishes.

It is same as saying in plain English - *I am blocked researching this topic and **won't get up to do anything else** unless I solve this mystery and post an answer about it*